# Realtime auto keying framing on the timeline don't work as expected on blender 2.81

Tags: animation, keyframes, pose-mode, object-mode

Hello blender masters.

I'm trying to track and save on the timeline the facial movements of a character using OPEN CV and two custom python scripts that I found here :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY_eErKlilw

I'm using blender 2.81. This is how it works : after having loaded and ran the two python scripts I go in **object mode** and I click on the last icon located on the left of the screen,called **"Open CV animation"**. As soon as I do that,a new icon called **"OpenCV animation"** appears on the right of the screen,under the **Active Tool** tab. After that I click on **"Capture"** and a new window appears. It is the OpenCV output window that shows that it starts tracking the face movements of the man on the source video. At the same time I open the tool **manycam** and I load inside it the video of the man who is talking. Good.

The 3d character that's inside the 3d view of blender starts moving,reacting to the facial movements of the man who is talking. Now,what I want to do is to save on the blender time line the facial movements of the 3d character in realtime,as soon as they are created. The problem is that when I'm on **object mode** and I click on **"auto keying"** no keyframes are added.

[image]

I tried also to click the **"auto keying"** button even when I'm on the **pose mode**,but also,no keyframes are added to the timeline. Can you give me some suggestion ?

I have attached a recorded video to show you what I do. thanks.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hDZ4qIlagSGhSum_mz1L0W0IHhBWZoJm

Answer (score 0):

If you need to record an animation on the fly, you have to start the playback first. So that time goes on in Blender's point of view and it can record what you each frame passing by:

[image: demo picture]

Without that, time isn't involved, only the frame under your playhead can be keyed, and it will only do so when a transform is validated (like when you move your object somewhere and release your mouse button to confirm).

Hopefully this is just what you need.

Comment: watch this : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eRFSVhp2o4r3N99d7b1Cv8-WBAl_3FDt ; it seems that it worked,even if I don't see that it added the yellow diamonds on the time line. do u know why ?

Comment: If I don't see the keyframes added,I can't slow down the animation.

Comment: Weird weird... Maybe look at the Nonlinear editor or the outliner in action editor mode, to see if the animation was recorded in an action that is not loaded in the timeline but still playing.